# How do you verify the key given by remmina (libfreerdp2)

Tags: certificates, linux, windows-10, remote-desktop

This morning I took an update to remmina and started getting a "fingerprint changed" warning. When using xfreerdp (from freerdp-x11) I get they old key. The old key being 20 bytes and the new key being 32 bytes.

I originally thought this made it a remmina bug, but changing to freerdp2-x11 gets the new key.

The thing is I knew were to find the thumbprint to verify the old key (It is in certlm.msc "Remote Desktop" folder). I have no idea where this new key is coming from and nothing so far seems to tell me how to make sure it's really coming from my Windows 10 install. It appears most notes I see on this just tell the user to accept the new key or turn on "ignore invalid certificate" and no mention of how to verify this 32 byte key.

So I'm desperately trying to find out if there is anyone who knows where this new 32 Byte key is coming from and how do I check it against the Windows host?

Answer (score 1):

`freerdp` is now displaying the remote desktop thumbprint in SHA256 format.  Before that, it was displaying it in SHA1 format.  Windows is still displaying it in SHA1 format hence when you look at it visually, the numbers don't match.

You can extract the certificate in Windows and generate a SHA256 for the certificate. Run the following on the extracted certificate:

```
openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha256 -inform der -in remotedesktop_cert_der_x509.cer
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick check just now and in my case (Windows 10), the "Fingerprint" that `remmina` presents to me is the `Thumbprint` you can find on the certificate under Remote Desktop on `certlm.msc` console.

This is the same certificate that is presented on the RDP port if you connect with a generic TLS tool like `openssl s_client -connect <host>:3389`.

Comment: Well the problem is Windows 10 only shows the SHA-1 Thumbprint and libfreerdp2 is using the sha256 thumbprint. But a search gave me the addition:

openssl s_client -connect <host>:3389 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout -in /dev/stdin

Comment: ah, I see, I didn't actually get x509 do show the fingerprint, I just checked the cert was the same by serial.

Comment: @Pedro Serial is an arbitrary value.